# Benedict Gross's paper on companion forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

In the page 458 of his paper(A tameness criterion for Galois representations associated to modular forms), Gross wrote the following

"A detailed analysis of $U_p(Af)+V_p(<p>f)$ shows that it
vanishes at each supersingular point", 
(where $f$ is a mod p modular form of weight 1, $U_p$ is the Hecke operator on 
mod $p$ modular forms of weight p, $A$ is the Hasse invariant, $V_p$ is the $p$-power map, 
and $<p>$ is the diamond operator.)

Can someone explain how to do analysis of this section at supersingular points?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow!  You can use $\LaTeX$ syntax for math here; just enclose it in `$`.  Also, it would be nice to include the full citation of the paper; in particular, there are several mathematicians named Gross (and at least two number theorists).

Comment: Nate, who are the two Gross number theorists?

Comment: A search of MathSciNet for Author: Gross and MR Primary: 10 or 11 yields Samuel, Benedict, Robert, Warren, Christian, Herbert, Kenneth, and Oliver (but mostly Benedict).